# Group time-series observations in R

Tags: r, time-series

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeD6u.png)

I have a time seriesAnd I have values from 15 to 15 minutes (so I have 4 values per hour) but I am trying to reduce the data for clustering analysis.

I want to check if I can group per hour in R Software. So I think I need to check for similarities with some kind of statiscal test.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Best to provide a reproducible example and show what code have you tried so far. Otherwise it is difficult to answer.

Comment: What @USER_1 said. Are your data already formatted as a time series? What kind (e.g., `ts`, `zoo`, `xts`)? Can you provide a snippet with `dput` or some other way so we can test solutions against your specific problem?

Comment: @USER_1 Let's imagine that I have power records of 24 hours, every 15 minutes. I want to group per hour and I would do that using power average per hour. But I want to know if my power records per hour are similar in order to group them? Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: @AnaS90 Lets's imagine we can see the actual data... You really need to post some data otherwise it is not possible to give an answer.

Comment: @USER_1 I have put an example of what I have. Now, I know how to group the data. But I want to check whether I can or cannot do that. So, if I look to the first 4 records, how can I say they are similar? Is there a statistical test to do that?

Comment: I have put an example of what I have. Now, I know how to group the data. But I want to check whether I can or cannot do that. So, if I look to the first 4 records, how can I say they are similar? Is there a statistical test to do that? @ulfelder

Comment: That's a methods question, not a programming one, so best done on CrossValidated rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: @ufelder thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this general type of a problem you can use the xts package:

```
library(xts)

# convert your data to xts object
your.data.xts <- xts(data$value,
               as.POSIXct(data$time))
# aggregate by hour
hourly.apply(dat.xts,sum)
```

You could also use the base `aggregate()` function or `period.apply()` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rts/versions/1.0-12/topics/period.apply

In the future, please provide a reproducible example (with your data) when asking a question.

Comment: You can do this with `zoo` and `lubridate`, too: `new.ts <- aggregate(your.ts.as.zoo, by = lubridate::hour, sum)`.